# How to compare performance between desktop graphics card and laptop graphics card?

Tags: graphics, performance

For example, I know GT640 is better than GT640M.

1.Is GT630 better then GT640M?

2.Is GT620 better then GT640M?

3.Is GT610 better then GT640M?

How to check for their performance if I don't have any card before I want to buy?

Thank you~

Comment: Its an off topic.  Its not related to ubuntu. Please  have a look in [FAQ]

Comment: check out the http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=home  for comparisons and benchmarks , also having their own testsuite to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the card,

Research through internet. Read reviews and compare the posted benchmarks.

A list is over here - http://www.notebookcheck.net/Comparison-of-Laptop-Graphics-Cards.130.0.html